# How to iterate through files in a folder and apply my script to all in python

Tags: python, json

I have a script that loops through a file and extracts data where the entities are not null, however I can only do this for one file, while the folder has over 100 files. Here is my code that only runs through one file.

```
import json

#### Loads downloaded json file for processing

with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

#### Iterates through the json file and extracts only data where the entities are not null

data =([obj for obj in data if obj['entities']])

### checks where the value is entities and changes the name to labels

for elem in data:
     elem['labels'] = elem.pop('entities')

### downloads the output into a json file for further processing

with open('output.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

I am looking for a way I can apply this code to all the files in a folder with the path

Comment: Do your files have a consistent naming convention or are they random?

Comment: Its semi random here is the naming convention
 `RP20T1850993 - VSMCV_1.pdf.pag1.png.json`
The first part is what is different for each file.

Comment: You seem to be saving and loading files to the same folder. You will need to keep the input and output files separate if you want to glob over them

Comment: Perhaps you could use the `os` library to first get a list of the files, and then iterate over the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```py
import json, os

def process(json_file):
    # do your processing
    return processed_file

if __name__=="__main__":
    for file in os.listdir("input folder"): # Find all files in the input folder
         with open(os.path.join("input folder", file)) as f: 
             data = json.load(f) # load the file
         data = process(data)
         with open(os.path.join("output folder", file), 'w') as f;
              json.dump(data, f) # save the file in "output folder"
```

Rename "input folder" and "output folder" to folders that exist.

Comment: Getting this error using the above code .
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jowey\Desktop\python\import.py", line 13, in <module>
    json.dump(data, f) # save the file in "output folder"
  File "c:\python\python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 180, in dump
    fp.write(chunk)
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable`

Comment: @Jowey Sorry, you need to open the file in write mode. I edited my answer